# Arduino code/ran out of storage/ arduino uno

Tags: arduino

I am trying to make an Arduino project that has 3 functions; play piano keyboard, play random song, and be able to play and record for playback. So far, I've met all three of these functions. The problem is my storage on my arduino, I completely ran out space and can't insert any more music code inside. At the moment, I have one song only, but I want to add more. Do I have to get an arduino mega or edit the code?
-Thank you!

Here's my code:

```
#include "pitches.h"
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3 ,2);
int notes[] = { NOTE_G4, NOTE_D6};

int button_music = 0;
int button2 =0;
int randNumber;

int key1 = 0;
int key2 = 0;
int recorded_button[200];
int recorded_time[200];
int pev_button;
char button = 0;
char button_index = 0;
int note_time;
unsigned long start_time;
char time_index;






void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  pinMode(A5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, INPUT);
  pinMode(9,INPUT);
  // put your setup code here
}

void loop() {
 button_music = digitalRead(A4);
 button2 = digitalRead(A5);
 key1 = digitalRead(7);
 key2 = digitalRead(6);
 lcd.setCursor(0,0);
 lcd.print("Press button to"); 
 lcd.setCursor(0,1);
 lcd.print("play random song");
 if(button_music == HIGH) {
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("In Progress...");
      delay(5000);
      randNumber = random(1,4);
      Serial.println(randNumber);
      if(randNumber == 1) {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("Tetris Theme...");
        delay(1000);
        }
      else if(randNumber == 2) {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("USSR Theme...");
        USSR_Theme();
        delay(1000);
        }
       else if(randNumber == 3) {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("Pirates of the");
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        lcd.print("Caribbean...");
        delay(1000);
         }
     }
  else if(key1 == HIGH){
//      lcd.clear();
//      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
//      lcd.print("Hey You");
//      delay(2000);
      tone(A0,NOTE_G4,20);

    }
  else if (key2 == HIGH) {
    tone(A0,NOTE_D6,20);
    }

   // 3rd funtion (record)
   else if(digitalRead(9) == 1) {
    lcd.clear();
    delay(20);
        while(digitalRead(8) == 0) {
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0); lcd.print("Recording..");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);

      Detect_button();
      Play_tone();
          }
////////////////////////////////
  while (digitalRead(8) == 1) //If the toggle switch is set in Playing mode
  {
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);  
  lcd.print("Now Playing..");

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(recorded_button) / 2; i++)
  {
    delay((recorded_time[i]) * 10); //Wait for before paying next tune

    if (recorded_button[i] == 0)
      noTone(A0); //user dint touch any button
    else
      tone(A0, notes[(recorded_button[i] - 1)]); //play the sound corresponding to the button touched by the user
  }
  }


////////////////////////////          
       // }
   }

}

void Detect_button(){
  key1 = digitalRead(7);
  key2 = digitalRead(6);
  pev_button = button;
  if(key1 != HIGH && key2 != HIGH) {
    button = 0;
    }

  if (key1 ==
  HIGH){
    button = 1;
  }

  if (key2 == HIGH){
    button = 2;
  }

  /***record the pressed buttons in a array**/
    if (button != pev_button && pev_button != 0)
  {
    recorded_button[button_index] = pev_button; 
    button_index++;
    recorded_button[button_index] = 0;
    button_index++;
  }
  //**end of recording**//
}

void Play_tone(){

  //**record time delay between notes**//
  if (button != pev_button)
  {
    lcd.clear();
    note_time = (millis() - start_time) / 10;

    recorded_time[time_index] = note_time;
    time_index++;

    start_time = millis();
    }
    //**end of recording **//

   if (button == 0) {
    noTone(A0);
    lcd.print("Pause");
    }
   if (button == 1)  {
    tone(A0,NOTE_G4,20);
    lcd.print("NOTE G4");
    }
   if (button == 2) {
    tone(A0, NOTE_D6, 20);
    lcd.print("NOTE D6");
    }


  }


void USSR_Theme(){
  int buzzerPin = 7;

int melody[] = {
  NOTE_G4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_G4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_B4, NOTE_E4, NOTE_E4, 
  NOTE_A4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_F4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_C4, NOTE_C4, 
  NOTE_D4, NOTE_D4, NOTE_E4, NOTE_F4, NOTE_F4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_B4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, 
  NOTE_E5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_B4, NOTE_G4, 
  NOTE_C5, NOTE_B4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_B4, NOTE_E4, NOTE_E4, 
  NOTE_A4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_F4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_C4, NOTE_C4, 
  NOTE_C5, NOTE_B4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_B4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, 
  NOTE_E5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_C5, NOTE_B4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_G4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_B4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5,
  NOTE_C5, NOTE_B4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_B4, NOTE_E4, NOTE_E4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_B4,
  NOTE_C5, NOTE_A4, NOTE_B4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_A4, NOTE_B4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_A4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_F5,
  NOTE_F5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_C5, NOTE_C5,
  NOTE_D5, NOTE_C5, NOTE_B4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_B4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_A4, NOTE_A4,
  NOTE_C5, NOTE_B4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_C4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_B4, NOTE_C5
};

int noteDurations[] = {
  8, 4, 6, 16, 4, 8, 8, 
  4, 6, 16, 4, 8, 8, 
  4, 8, 8, 4, 8, 8, 4, 8, 8, 2,
  4, 6, 16, 4, 8, 8, 
  4, 6, 16, 4, 8, 8, 
  4, 6, 16, 4, 6, 16, 
  4, 6, 16, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
  2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 3, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
  2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 3, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
  4, 6, 16, 4, 6, 16, 4, 8, 8, 2,
  2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 3, 8, 2,
  2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 3, 8, 2,
  4, 6, 16, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 1
};
  for (int thisNote = 0; thisNote < sizeof(melody) / 2; thisNote++) {
    int noteDuration = 2000 / noteDurations[thisNote];
    tone(A0, melody[thisNote], noteDuration);
    int pauseBetweenNotes = noteDuration * 1.30;
    delay(pauseBetweenNotes);
    noTone(buzzerPin);


  }

}
```

Comment: Read the datasheet for the part you're using.

Comment: use PROGMEM to save SRAM and SD card to save flash memory

Comment: @Juraj:PROGMEM for songs,  F-Macro for texts is easy to do. If the MEGA2560's FLASH is sufficient, that's easier than adding an SD card (which takes a lot of RAM on an Uno)

Comment: PROGMEM https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/progmem/